# To generate a fresh grid every time button is clicked

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

This is the html code being used to generate a grid. When submit button is hit it is generating a new grid and adding it at the end of old grid.

```
<form id="sizePicker">
    Grid Height:
    <input type="number" id="input_height" name="height" min="1" value="1">
    Grid Width:
    <input type="number" id="input_width" name="width" min="1" value="1">
    <button id="Button" type="button">submit</button>
</form>
<h2>Design Canvas</h2>
<table id="pixel_canvas"></table>
```

This is the javascript code used.

```
const inputHeight = $('#input_height');
const inputWidth = $('#input_width');
function makeGrid() {
    const height = parseInt(inputHeight.val());
    const width = parseInt(inputWidth.val());
    for(let row = 0; row < height; row++) {
        const tr = $('<tr></tr>');
        for(let cell = 0; cell < width; cell++) {
            tr.append('<td></td>');
        }
        $('#pixel_canvas').append(tr);
    }
}
$('#Button').on('click', makeGrid);
```

How can we solve this?

Comment: What problem needs solving? What's your specific problem and question?

Comment: Also, post all the relevant code. Where is `#pixel_canvas`?

Comment: Also, you don't actually have a `submit` button (which is good because you don't actually submit data anywhere). You have a `button` button.

Comment: I added the code @ScottMarcus

Comment: Great! Now, can you please address my first comment?

Comment: @ScottMarcus I need to generate a fresh grid everytime the button is clicked. In this case, everytime i click the button, the new grid generated is getting added at the end of the older one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You use jQuery [append()](http://api.jquery.com/append/) which does exactly what you're saying - adding new rows to existing element:

> Insert content, specified by the parameter, to the end of each element
>   in the set of matched elements.

You need to either empty the element before appending, or even better, generate new content, than use jQuery [html()](http://api.jquery.com/html/) method to set element's html:

```
const inputHeight = $('#input_height');
const inputWidth = $('#input_width');
function makeGrid() {
    const height = parseInt(inputHeight.val());
    const width = parseInt(inputWidth.val());
    var newGridHtml = ''; /* Here we generate grid HTML */
    for(let row = 0; row < height; row++) {
        newGridHtml += '<tr>';
        for(let cell = 0; cell < width; cell++) {
            newGridHtml += '<td></td>';
        }
        newGridHtml += '</tr>';
    }
    $('#pixel_canvas').html( newGridHtml ); /* No appending here */
}
$('#Button').on('click', makeGrid);
```

What `html()` does is:

> Get the HTML contents of the first element in the set of matched
>   elements **or set the HTML contents of every matched element**.